# How do I make a PHP CLI script "call for attention" on Windows 10?

Tags: php, command-line, windows-10, taskbar

Icons on the Taskbar, or in an icon group in the Taskbar, can "blink" for attention. All kinds of programs do this all the time when they need human attention.

Now I want to do that for my own PHP CLI scripts (running as cmd.exe windows).

How do I accomplish this? I've tried several things with that ASCII "bell" thing, after being told about this, but it never works. The bell character neither makes the icon blink nor play a sound on Windows 10. So that is not the right solution.

I've searched for this for a long time, but I never get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The blink think may not be possible in Windows 10. But perhaps you can use color. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/413073/windows-console-with-ansi-colors-handling/1300251#1300251) to learn how to turn on Ansi Terminal Control in Win 10.

You may find this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) helpful for learning the escape codes.

The blink "command" would be `ESC [5m`. I could not get it to work, and a search around the internet did not find any indication that it can work.

Here is an example in php that uses color.

```
echo chr(7); //Bell

echo chr(27)."[1;31;103m"; // 1= bright 31 = foreground color red 103 = background color yellow

echo "\nDANGER WILL ROBINSON\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";
echo "PAY ATTENTION\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";

echo chr(27)."[0m"; // turn off formatting
```